# Android ListView not being populated by custom ParseQueryAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

for an app I am making I am attempting to populate a listView with data obtained from parse.com using a custom parsequeryadapter subclass. Basically it just shows a blank activity when opening the activity.

**Adapter code**

```
package com.example.battlesim;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

public class LeaderboardAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {
    public Context context;

    public LeaderboardAdapter(Context c) {
        super(c, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>(){


            public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create(){
//          public final ArrayList<String> leadersName;
//          public final ArrayList<Integer> leadersScore;
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryL = ParseQuery.getQuery("Character");
            queryL = queryL.whereNotEqualTo("name", null);
            queryL = queryL.orderByDescending("level");
            queryL.setLimit(10);
            try {
                queryL.find();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return queryL;

//          queryL.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
//              public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
//                  if (e == null) {
//                      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
//                          leadersName.add(scoreList.get(i).getString("name"));
//                          leadersScore.add(scoreList.get(i).getInt("level"));
//                      }
//                  } else {
//                      Log.d("level", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
//                  }
//              }

            }
        });
        this.context = c;
    }



    public View getItemView(ParseObject o, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View vi = convertView;
        if(convertView == null) vi = View.inflate(getContext(),  R.layout.board, null);
        super.getItemView(o, convertView, parent);
        TextView name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView level = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.level);

        name.setText(o.getString("name"));
        level.setText(o.getInt("level"));

        return vi;
    }

}
```

**Activity onCreate code**

```
LeaderboardAdapter adapter = new LeaderboardAdapter(this);
    adapter.loadObjects();

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Board.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:textSize="25dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/level"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:textSize="25dip"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry if I formatted anything oddly or forgot to include anything. I'm new to StackExchange and somewhat new to Android programming

Comment: Can you provide any error messages here?

Comment: Sadly, given the current code there are no error messages. At least not that I know of because the code doesn't cause the app to crash. Should I try and put a log message somewhere in the code to see what's not working? If so, where would be the best place to put that?

Comment: I would set a breakpoint near the beginning of the program. Then F6 (step over) until you don't see your desired result. F5 if you want to dig into the code a little further. Note, you can also put debug lines in your code too, but don't rely on that since you can't really see what's going on; the debugger is your friend.

Comment: Ah, I've never tried debugging in Android with the debugger. How does that work compared to debugging in Java?

Comment: Its roughly the same. Set a break point and dig. :) Assuming you are using Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Replace `queryL.whereNotEqualTo("name", null);` with `queryL.whereExists("name");`